# SVG の線の長さと同じ値はどうやって探すんですか？

Tags: html, css, svg

[CSS animation で遊び倒す　-SVG Line -  - Qiita](https://qiita.com/duka/items/4ced752bb257884736f9)を読んでいます。

> 1. 破線の間隔が、SVG の線の長さと同じ値を探し、stroke-dasharrayに設定して、全てを隠します。

「SVG の線の長さと同じ値を探し」とはどのように探すのでしょうか？

コードの該当箇所の引用：

```
stroke-dasharray: 700px;
stroke-dashoffset: 700px;
```

700pxとあるので、SVGを描いている下記コードに`700`があるのかと思ったのですが、ありませんでした。

SVG部分（引用）

```
<svg
  width="288"
  height="175"
  viewBox="0 0 288 175"
  fill="none"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
>
  <path
    d="M1 143.5C28.6 143.1 42.5 143.333 46 143.5C52.3333 128.834 70.2 108.3 91 143.5H109L113.5 174.5L133.5 1L159.5 174.5L167 143.5H201C208.167 134.5 227.5 121.9 247.5 143.5H287.5"
    stroke="black"
  />
</svg>
```

どうやって `stroke-dasharray` の値が決定されたのでしょうか？

Comment: 記事からリンクされている動画では、画像を見ながら適当に大きくしていって実験的に求めているようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

指定する値は, SVG内の `path`の長さ以上であればよいので 必ずしも同じでなくても構わないはず

デバッガーにその手の情報の取得が可能か不明だったので, 以下のようにして取得
JavaScriptから SVG参照できるように用意し, 実行することで, `path`の長さが判明します
(実行前に, SVG 要素に `id="pls"`属性追加し(ここでは適当な名前), 参照できるようにした)

```js
<script>
var path = document.querySelector('#pls path');
console.log(path.getTotalLength()); // 666.5587158203125
</script>
```